# How to setup a crontab that runs in some separate days?

Tags: cron

How to setup a crontab that starts on: 5, 7 and 10 of the month at 00:30?
Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the format of cron is MIN HOUR DAYOFMONTH MONTH DAYOFWEEK, this should work.

```
30 0 5,7,10 * * script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

`30 0 5,7,10 * * COMMAND`

First number = minutes (30)
Second = hours (0)
Third = comma separated list of days of the month (5th, 7th and 10th)
Fourth = Months of the year (* = every month)
Fifth = Days of the week (* every day of the week - but still honouring the third option)